# How to handle seemingly irrelevant language tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the C++ tag and I've seen several questions about various APIs and tools that don't have a single line of C++, ask a question that would specifically apply to C++, or ask for their question to be answered in a C++ implementation.

Questions like:

- [glsl applying shader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22919/glsl-applying-shader?rq=1)
- [Can't load own .obj-files from Blender to DX11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119288/cant-load-own-obj-files-from-blender-to-dx11)
- [glsl 150 struct in uniform buffer object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50040/glsl-150-struct-in-uniform-buffer-object?rq=1)
- [variable number of lights in a glsl shader?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53822/variable-number-of-lights-in-a-glsl-shader?rq=1)
- [Non-real time simulation of overlapping repulsive balls](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118819/non-real-time-simulation-of-overlapping-repulsive-balls)

These do not contain or relate to C++ and are general GLSL/OpenGL/DirectX/CUDA questions that could easily be answered with language agnostic solutions or without any code at all. Would it not be better to expressly ask for the solution to be given with a C++ implementation in mind instead of the question being tagged with `c++`? Would it be beneficial to remove the `c++` tag in questions like these?
I've read [Are language tags useless?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/are-language-tags-useless) and its accepted answers and I really don't see a benefit in searching/filtering for an unrelated tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the tag if you can.

We should not be artificially making our questions more specific than they need to be; see also [this recent discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-performing-a-task-with-a-specific-tool).

Try to make other improvements in your edit as well, especially if you are under the reputation threshold that still requires your edits to be approved.

Comment: Thank you, that was basically what I was afraid to do, I figured I'd just be making a mess for the mods if I started making a bunch of edits where I only removed the C++ tag to clear up something that probably doesn't bother many people much.

Comment: @MattJensJensen It won't cause problems. Edits that require approval (as yours currently would I think, given your reputation) often *do* get rejected for being too minor though, which is why I suggested trying to make other substantive edits as well (or at least include a good edit comment).

Comment: I'll do my best to try to provide some more substantial value to my future edits, I felt bad immediately after re-tagging a question very similar to the ones I've linked to in this question realizing that someone actually has to go through and approve that minor edit.